# Something wrong while deleting a row in sql table on clicking a button

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to delete a row from my SQL table in my shopping cart page,but my code deletes all the rows from the table on clicking a button.Even when I update quantity of the one product the quantity of all the products are changing.The answer might be the same for these two issues.Could you please review my code and tell me where I've done wrong.

Thankyou in advance

```
    <?php 
    include "header.php";
    require "includes/connect.php";
    require "includes/product.php";
    class Cartitem{
        public function fetch_cart(){
            global $pdo;
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM  cart_items WHERE user_id = ?");
            $query->bindvalue(1, $_SESSION['user_id']);
            $query -> execute();
            return $query->fetchAll();
        }
    }
    $cartitem= new Cartitem;    
    $cartitems=$cartitem-> fetch_cart(); 

?>
<div class="cart">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="col-md-9 cart-items">
        <h1 class="cart-items-h1">Cart</h1>
        <hr>

        <?php foreach($cartitems as $cartitem) { ?>
        <div class="cart-header">
            <h3> 
            <a href="productpage.php?id=<?php echo $cartitem['product_id'] ;?> "><?php echo $cartitem['product_name'] ; ?></a></h3>
            <br>
            <?php 

                if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
                $query = $pdo->prepare('DELETE  FROM cart_items WHERE  product_id=?');
                $query->bindValue(1 , $cartitem['product_id']);
                $query->execute();

            }
            ?>
            <form method = "POST" action="">
                <button type="submit" class="close btn btn-default" name="delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove " aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            </form>

            <div class="cart-sec simpleCart_shelfItem">
                <div class="cart-item cyc">
                    <img src="Tiger.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=" No image"/>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-item-info">
                    <ul class="item-properties">
                       <li>
                        <form action="" method="post">

                            <?php 
                            if(isset($_POST['qty'])){ 
                                $quantity=$_POST['qty'];
                                $query = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE cart_items SET quantity= ? WHERE  product_id=?');
                                $query->bindValue(1 , $quantity);
                                $query->bindValue(2 , $cartitem['product_id']);
                                $query->execute();
                            }
                            ?>
                            <select class="quantity"  name="qty">
                            <?php
                                echo '<option >'.$cartitem['quantity'].'</option>';
                                for($q = 1 ; $q<10 ; $q++){
                                    echo '<option >'.$q.'</option>';
                                }

                            ?>
                            </select>
                            <button type="submit" class="update" name="update">Update</button>
                       </li>
                       <li><p>Rs.<?php echo $cartitem['price']; ?></p></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="delivery">
                        <p>Service Charges : Rs.190.00</p>
                        <span>Delivered in 2-3 bussiness days</span>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>      
        <?php }?>
        </div>
```

> This is (productpage.php) from where I'm storing the values to the cart table.Probably not so important to this issue. If yes

```
    <?php 
    ob_start();
    include ('header.php');
    require('includes/connect.php');
    require('includes/product.php');

    $product = new Product;         
    if(isset ($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $data = $product -> fetch_data($id);    


        if(isset($_POST['add'])){
            if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
                $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT product_id FROM cart_items WHERE product_id= ?");
                    $query -> bindValue(1, $id);
                    $query ->execute();
                    $num=$query->rowCount();
                    if($num == 0){
                    if(isset($_POST['qty'])){
                        $qty=$_POST['qty'];
                    }
                    $query = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO cart_items(product_id , user_id, quantity,price,product_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
                    $query -> bindValue(1, $id);
                    $query -> bindValue(2, $_SESSION['user_id']);
                    $query -> bindValue(3, $qty);
                    $query -> bindValue(4, $data['new_price']);
                    $query -> bindValue(5, $data['product_name']);
                    $query ->execute();
                    header('location:cart.php');
                    }
                    else{
                        echo " The product is already in your Cart";
                    }
            }
            else{
                header('location:Login Page.php');
            }
        }
?>
    <div class="showcase-grid">
        <div class="container ">
                            <?php if(isset($error)){ ?>
                                        <small style = "color : #aa0000"; ><?php echo $error ?></small>
                                        <br><br>
                                <?php } ?>
            <div class="col-md-8  showcase"  id="showcase-div">
                <div class="img-showcase" >
                    <br> 
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide text-center" data-ride="carousel">
                          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=" img-responsive"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="img-responsive"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="img-responsive"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class="img-responsive"></li>
                          </ol>
                           <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active">
                                  <img class="slide-img" src="images/product2.jpg" alt="jwellery" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                  <img src="images/product3.jpg" alt="jwellery">
                                </div>

                                <div class="item">
                                  <img src="images/product4.jpg" alt="jwellery" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                  <img src="images/product5.jpg" alt="jwellery" >
                                </div>
                          </div>
                          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                          </a>
                          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                          </a>
                    </div>  
                    <br>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4  showcase1 ">
                    <div class="showcase-rt-top">
                        <div class = "row">
                            <div class ="col-md-12">
                            <br>
                                <div class="pull-left Product-name">
                                    <h3><?php echo $data['product_name']; ?></h3>
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br><br><br>
                            <div class ="col-xs-4 price">
                                <h4>Rs.<?php echo $data['new_price']; ?></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class ="col-xs-4 oldprice text-left">
                                <s><h4 class="text-left">Rs.<?php echo $data['old_price']; ?></h4></s>
                            </div>
                            <div class ="col-xs-4">
                                <div class="pull-right rating-stars pull-left">
                                <h4><span class="label label-warning">3.5 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star-stn" aria-hidden="true"></span></span></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="featurette-divider">

                        <div class="shocase-rt-bot">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 discount">
                            <?php
                                $discount = (($data['old_price'] - $data['new_price'])/$data['old_price'])*100;
                                echo round($discount) . '% off ';
                            ?>
                            </div>
                            <form action = "" method="post" class="form-inline">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="float-qty-chart">
                                        <!--    <label class=" option">quantity:</label>-->
                                            <select id= "select" class="form-control qnty-chrt"  name="qty" >
                                                <option value="1">quantity</option>
                                                <option>1</option>
                                                <option>2</option>
                                                <option>3</option>
                                                <option>4</option>
                                                <option>5</option>
                                                <option>6</option>
                                                <option>7</option>
                                            </select>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="ul_list">
                                    <li class="ad-2-crt simpleCart_shelfItem">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn item_add" name="add" >Add To Cart</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn item_add" name="buy-now">Buy Button</button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <br>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                    <div class="features" >
                        <h3>product details</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><?php echo  nl2br($data['brief_description']); ?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
else{
    header('location: index.php');
    exit();
}
Include ('footer.php');
?>
```

> This is the product.php

```
<?php
class Product {
    public function fetch_all() {
        global $pdo;
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ear_rings_list");
        $query -> execute();
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
    public function fetch_data($pid) {
        global $pdo;
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ear_rings_list WHERE listing_id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $pid);
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetch();
    }
}
```

Comment: remove `if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
                $query = $pdo->prepare('DELETE  FROM cart_items WHERE  product_id=?');
                $query->bindValue(1 , $cartitem['product_id']);
                $query->execute();` from loop

Comment: Are you sure you have no other items belong to other users ? may be all the rows in the `cart_items` table are belong to 1 user

Comment: If I do like that does the array works.

Comment: @urfusion **Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Cartitem as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce\cart.php on line 27** this is the error I'm getting.

Comment: @Accountantم All the products belongs to only 1 user and it only displays the items of logged user.But I want to delete the row with reference to the Product_id in the query.

Comment: @SrikarReddy then your code is not broken, it deletes all the cart items for the current user which happens to be all the rows in the table. `$cartitems` has all the rows in the table after you executed that query `SELECT * FROM  cart_items WHERE user_id = ?`

Comment: @Accountantم Even if there are 3 users cart items in the table it only deletes only one users items with reference to user id .But I wrote the query to delete the single row with reference to the product_id which is not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are working with an **foreach** loop
Just check here

```
  <?php foreach($cartitems as $cartitem) { ?>
   if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
       $query = $pdo->prepare('DELETE  FROM cart_items WHERE  product_id=?');
       $query->bindValue(1 , $cartitem['product_id']);
       $query->execute();
    }
  if(isset($_POST['qty'])){ 
     $quantity=$_POST['qty'];
     $query = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE cart_items SET quantity= ? WHERE  product_id=?');
     $query->bindValue(1 , $quantity);
     $query->bindValue(2 , $cartitem['product_id']);
     $query->execute();
  }
 <?php }?>
```

Here you are just checking the `isset($_POST['delete'])` which will be **true** for **each** `$cartitem['product_id']` that's why your **each row is deleting** and updating.

**Solution:-**
Use this code

```
<?php
include "header.php";
require "includes/connect.php";
require "includes/product.php";
class Cartitem
{
public function fetch_cart()
{
global $pdo;
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM  cart_items WHERE user_id = ?");
$query->bindvalue(1, $_SESSION['user_id']);
$query->execute();
return $query->fetchAll();
}
}
$cartitem = new Cartitem;
$cartitems = $cartitem->fetch_cart();

?>
<div class="cart">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-9 cart-items">
    <h1 class="cart-items-h1">Cart</h1>
    <hr>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['qty']) && isset($_POST['product_id'])) {
        $quantity = $_POST['qty'];
        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
        $query = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE cart_items SET quantity= ? WHERE  product_id=?');
        $query->bindValue(1, $quantity);
        $query->bindValue(2, $product_id);
        $query->execute();
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['product_id'])) {
        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
        $query = $pdo->prepare('DELETE  FROM cart_items WHERE  product_id=?');
        $query->bindValue(1, $product_id);
        $query->execute();
    }
    ?>
    <?php foreach($cartitems as $cartitem) { ?>
    <div class="cart-header">
        <h3>
            <a href="productpage.php?id=<?php echo $cartitem['product_id'];?> "><?php echo $cartitem['product_name']; ?></a></h3>
        <br>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php $cartitem['product_id'] ?>" name="product_id">
            <button type="submit" class="close btn btn-default" name="delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove " aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </form>

        <div class="cart-sec simpleCart_shelfItem">
            <div class="cart-item cyc">
                <img src="Tiger.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=" No image"/>
            </div>
            <div class="cart-item-info">
                <ul class="item-properties">
                    <li>
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php $cartitem['product_id'] ?>" name="product_id">
                            <select class="quantity" name="qty">
                                <?php
                                echo '<option >' . $cartitem['quantity'] . '</option>';
                                for ($q = 1; $q < 10; $q++) {
                                    echo '<option >' . $q . '</option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                            <button type="submit" class="update" name="update">Update</button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                    <li><p>Rs.<?php echo $cartitem['price']; ?></p></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="delivery">
                    <p>Service Charges : Rs.190.00</p>
                    <span>Delivered in 2-3 bussiness days</span>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>
```

**Changes :-**
I just make an **hidden input field** for `$cartitem['product_id']` here `<input type="hidden" value="<?php $cartitem['product_id'] ?>" name="product_id">`
and placed the **delete** and **update** query out side the **foreach loop**.

Comment: Yes you are right. I thought this already but I couldn't think how to address the specific product_id of the product which i want to delete.
It doesn't work out side the loop because it will be out side the array.
So any idea?

Comment: @Srikar Reddy use the solution it will work for you.Remember about input field and queries.

Comment: Good thought on adding a hidden field for address a product_id out side the array,thankyou.With very small changes in your solution the code is working very good.

Comment: Need to reload the page to reflect updated quantity and deleted item may be I need to add some ajax code right?

Comment: Just place '`$cartitem = new Cartitem;
$cartitems = $cartitem->fetch_cart();' after delete and update query then it will automatically reflect updated quantity and deleted items.

Comment: Yea you are right that's working excellent.But why like that , could you give a small one line explanation.

Comment: before you are selecting data and then delete or update query run ,now we are delete or update the database before retrieving data.

Comment: Bro, how to use the variable outside the for each loop( this time there is no button like earlier).I want to do this because I need to multiply the price with the quantity.Tried with the above method but its not possible.